# Exporting multiple sas datasets into multiple excel sheets with macro?

Tags: excel, sas, export, proc

I am looking if there is a macro that would export multiple datasets into separate excel worksheets within a workbook. Would be great if I could have 10 sheets per workbook.

I can do it the usual way as below, but I have more than 100 datasets to export:

```
PROC EXPORT DATA=HAVE;
OUTFILE= "S:\MYEXCEL.xlsx" 
        DBMS=EXCEL REPLACE;
SHEET="NEW_SHEET"; 
RUN;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The general concept is that you would do something like this:

```
%macro export_data(file=,data=,sheet=);
proc export data=&data.
outfile="&file."
dbms=excel replace;
sheet="&sheet.";
run;
%mend export_data;
```

Then you need to construct your export macro calls however you want.  Get a dataset with one row per dataset (use `dictionary.tables` in SQL or `sashelp.vtable` in data step) and work out however you want to the logic of the sheet names and how many workbooks you need.  Google data-driven macro calls for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have 'SAS/Access to PC FIle formats' licensed, this little macro does it effortlessly:

```
%macro SASToExcel(ImportLibrary=, ExportLocation=);

    ods output members = _Members;
    proc datasets lib = &ImportLibrary; run; quit;

    proc sql;
        select count(Name) into :NumOfDatasets from _Members;
        select Name into :Dataset1-:Dataset%trim(%left(&NumOfDatasets)) from _Members;
    quit;

    %do index = 1 %to &NumOfDatasets;
        proc export data=&ImportLibrary..&&Dataset&index.
        outfile="&ExportLocation"
        dbms=excel replace;
        sheet="&&Dataset&index";
        run;
    %end;

    proc datasets;
        delete _Members;
    quit;

%mend;

%SASToExcel(ImportLibrary=raw, ExportLocation = c:\test.xlsx);
```

Comment: Thank you!! I am adding this to my tool box :)